# Can't install Astropy for Python: where is the git repository?

Tags: software-installation, python, repository

I'm trying to install Astropy on Ubuntu 16.06 following the instructions given in the website [Installation - Astropy](http://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#building-from-source). I have run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install git
git clone  git://github.com/astropy/astropy.git
```

But now it won't let me do anything else: if I type

```
python setup.py build
```

or

```
python setup.py install
```

it gives me the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and Python, but I suppose this is happening because I'm not positioned where the git repository was stored. So, where is it and how can I install Astropy successfully?

Comment: If you ran `git clone git://github.com/astropy/astropy.git` then by default it will have cloned into `astropy` in the current directory: to change to that directory, type `cd astropy`

Comment: And if I don't have any idea what my current directory was when I cloned it? Any way I can find it without looking around everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Astropy is in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. To install Astropy open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-astropy # for Python 2.x
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-astropy # for Python 3.x
```

The python-astropy and python3-astropy packages contain core functionality and some common tools needed for performing astronomy and astrophysics research with Python. Astropy is expected to be extended by a number of "affiliated packages" that are intended to work with the core package. *python-astropy-doc*, *python-h5p*y and *python-wcsaxes* are suggested packages for python-astropy.

The following Python code<sup>**1**</sup> is a simple test to check if the cosmology and units built-in functions of astropy are working correctly.

```
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
H0 = cosmo.H(0)
H0.value, H0.unit
```

The expected output is:

```
(69.32, Unit("km / (Mpc s)"))
```

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Source: [Cosmological Calculations (astropy.cosmology)](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cosmology/)</sub>

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, this solved it.  I guess I shouldn't have cloned the repository, would it be a good idea to delete it? Any clue as to where it might be stored? Also, can I see the source code for Astropy, and if so, how?

Comment: When I tried your test code, the first line produced this output in the terminal: from: can't read /var/mail/astropy.cosmology. What could be happening?

Comment: You can optionally delete the GitHub Repository for the Astropy core package if you no longer need it. To download the source code of python- astropy to your desktop run the command: `cd ~/Desktop/ && apt-get source python-astropy`

Comment: The test code in my answer runs successfully in my Ubuntu 16.04 which does not have `/var/mail/astropy.cosmology` in the filesystem.

Comment: All right, it runs fine now, my fault. But when I try to download the source code, this is the output:  Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Comment: Put a check mark to the left of *Source code* in *Software & Updates* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab -> *Source code* and authenticate this change in your software sources with your user password. Close Software & Updates, open the terminal and run `sudo apt-get update` to update your software sources.